# Print to a string without sprintf

Tags: .net, string, f#

In [A Peek into F# 4.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/25/a-peek-into-f-4-1/), the author demonstrated we could print to a string without `sprintf`:

```
let private tryParseWith tryParseFunc (s : string) =
    match (tryParseFunc s) with
    | true, x -> Ok x
    | false, _ -> Error ("%s is not capable of being parsed." s)
```

Can I not use `sprintf` because the compiler is smart to infer `StringFormat<string>` type and evaluate the expression to `string` value in F# 4.1 and newer?

Comment: Is it C# or F#? You tagged this question with C#

Comment: @KfirGuy C#6 supported `FormattableString` type for interpolating strings so I wonder if F# can also interpolate without `sprintf`.

Comment: It's just a typo in the example code.

Comment: Have a look at `ksprintf` if you want to create functions that behave like sprintf, but does more with the resulting string than just return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String interpolation is currently not a feature that can be found in F# (as of version 4.1).

See https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1001-StringInterpolation.md for the current string interpolation proposal.

Comment: If it hasn't been supported yet, how does the expression above evaluate `("%s is not capable of being parsed." s)`?

Comment: To me it seems to be a mistake in the sample code in the blog post. Wrote a comment on there asking for clarification. Skimmed https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.1/FS-1004-result-type.md and https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/964/files, and found no evidence that string interpolation is implemented into this feature.